# Turn all text on any page to a specific color

Tags: html, css

How can I turn all text on a page to a specific color?

1. Content (HTML and CSS) is user generated, so I cannot control classes for specific elements.
2. Since the page's html, classes, etc can vary tremendously (user generated), I can't write CSS that will target elements individually.

Originally, I had tried to use `!important` on the `body` like below, but forgot that any targeted CSS would override it.

```
body {
  color: white !important;
}
```

Is my only option to use javascript to apply an inline style to every element?

Comment: Can we see some of the code at hand?

Comment: Put `body , table , tr, td , div{color: white !important}` in the end. Include more HTML tags in the list.

Comment: @Durgesh Chaudhary: Read the question again.

Comment: meanwhile you are right, when you apply css on body tag with important property any other css may override it.    
The best way to do this is using jqury.

Comment: @BoltClock I did not get. Is it that if we put * !important in the end, it will not override the class selector overrides and id overrides declared earlier.

Comment: @Durgesh Chaudhary: Read point #2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use * selector, not only body.

```
* {color: #fff !important}
```

Comment: This seems to be just about the only legitimate use case of `*` and `!important` together (barring the question of why someone would want to control the text color, of all things, on user-generated HTML *and* CSS...).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Universal selector (i.e *)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#universal-selector) selector to select any element on page:

```
html * {
      color: white !important;
    }
```

OR You can use directly use like this:

```
* {
    color: white !important;
  }
```

Comment: Using `html *` or even `html body *` is better in the sense that it fights better against other stylesheets that may set the color using `!important`, too. There is no absolutely reliable way to win such a game, since for any selector, it is always possible to construct a selector with higher specificity.

Answer (score 1):

From the statement **user generated**, we can see that users will be able to add some inline styles, even `!important` ones. Then, your only solution is javascript (jquery example):

```
$("*").css("color", "#FFF");
```

Or filter the html to remove the styles with [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/), which you should be using to filter the javascript anyway (to avoid MANY kind of attacks on your web.

OLD ANSWER:

Use this within your html's head (not in the stylesheet) because it has preference over the  styles in separated files:

```
<style>
* {
color: #FFF!important;
}
</style>
```